# como emitir som clicar na resposta correta do quiz

Tags: android, android-studio

Bom dia, estou desenvolvendo um projeto de quiz de perguntas e resposta. Gostaria de saber como devo fazer para colocar som quando o App exibir a resposta correta?

Por exemplo se a resposta correta for doze o que fazer para o App emitir som
String[] correct_list = {"Doze"}

Comment: Faltam muitas  informções: 
linguagem, 
framework,
web, mobile, deskto, ..

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o MediaPlayer.

1 - Salve o arquivo de áudio na pasta `res/raw/` de seu projeto.

2 - Crie a instância do MediaPlayer:

```
val mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.som_resposta_correta)
```

3 - Chame o método start() do MediaPlayer quando o usuário acertar a resposta:

```
mediaPlayer?.start()
```